# Mikraos Gedolos Recommendation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash

Can anyone please suggest/recommend a pocket set of Mikraos Gedolos besides for the 48 book set Oz Vhadar one? I'm just looking for a pocket chumash with the basic meforshim.

Thanks so much, appreciate the response!!

Comment: Which are "the basic meforshim"? Please edit to clarify

Comment: Rashi, rambam, even Ezra, bal haturim, or hachayim etc.

Comment: U've'lechtechah ba'derech series

Comment: Hamaor makes a nice small 5-set (blue) but it's not really pocket size

Comment: I forget what נחמד למראה has in their pocket edition.

Comment: The Mir publishing makes one that is a one-volume with many rishonim https://www.eichlers.com/google-shopping-categories/chumash-mikraos-gedolos-1-vol-student-size-hardcover.html (not sure if this is too small for you though)

Answer (score 2):

The only one other than the Oz Vehadar set that I came across was [the pocket Hamaor set](https://www.israelbookshop.com/chumash-hamaor-mikraos-gedolos-5-volume-set-small-size.html) - I imagine though due to it being a Mikraos Gedolos, it is likely to be quite thick and therefore somewhat cumbersome if you need it for travel purposes, although it does market it as being a 'pocket' set.